# How to upgrade resource to admin user role

Tags: magento2, role

I create an admin user role from setup using this code,

```
$role=$this->_roleFactory->create();
$role->setName('test') 
     ->setPid(0)
     ->setRoleType(RoleGroup::ROLE_TYPE) 
     ->setUserType(UserContextInterface::USER_TYPE_ADMIN); 

$role->save(); 
$resource=[
  'Magento_Backend::admin'
]; 

$this->_rulesFactory->create()
     ->setRoleId($role->getId())->setResources($resource)->saveRel();
```

But I want to add a new resource to this role, using `UpgradeData`.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it, using this code :

```
$role = $this->_roleCollection->addFieldToFilter('role_name', 'test')->getFirstItem();
$resource = $this->_aclRetriver->getAllowedResourcesByRole($role->getId());
array_push($resource,
   'Magento_Catalog::products'
);
$this->_rulesFactory->create()->setRoleId($role->getId())->setResources($resource)->saveRel();
```